# What is the time synchronization accuracy on Window 10?

Tags: windows-10

If I run

```
w32tm /query /status
```

I get the following output:

```
Leap Indicator: 0(no warning)
Stratum: 4 (secondary reference - syncd by (S)NTP)
Precision: -23 (119.209ns per tick)
Root Delay: 0.1015021s
Root Dispersion: 7.9757832s
ReferenceId: 0x3369D0AD (source IP:  51.105.208.173)
Last Successful Sync Time: 11/13/2020 3:58:50 AM
Source: time.windows.com,0x9
Poll Interval: 10 (1024s)
```

as far, as I can guess, the value 0.1015021s is some kind of a difference between the time on my machine and the time on the time server.

Is it possible to make this value about 0.001s (or 1ms) ?

Currently, after doing

```
w32tm /resync /force
```

I get about 0.1s all the time.

The command

```
w32tm /stripchart /computer:ru.pool.ntp.org /dataonly /samples:5
```

outputs the following:

```
Collecting 5 samples.
The current time is 11/13/2020 4:13:36 AM.
04:13:36, +00.2226197s
04:13:38, +00.2223258s
04:13:40, +00.2206661s
04:13:42, +00.2212902s
04:13:44, +00.2192719s
```

My understanding is that 00.2s is a terribly huge value. Why is the Windows time sync so inaccurate? For example, [Linux allows easily have synchronize with 1ms accuracy](https://developernote.com/2018/12/setting-up-time-synchronization-on-ubuntu/).

Comment: Beware that precision is not the same as accuracy!  If you don't know the network latency and/or it's random/variable, then perfect time synchronization is impossible.  See  https://www.masterclock.com/support/library/network-timing-ntp-vs-ptp

Comment: @sawdust I do not have enough time to investigate the time, I switched to Linux and got 1ms precision or accuracy (or something else), see https://developernote.com/2020/11/a-proper-ubuntu-18-04-installation-for-running-ethereum-node/#time (as far as I understand at least)